# Why is the unit vector perpendicular to the position vector given by $\frac{y\hat{i} - x\hat{j}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: vectors

Why is the unit vector perpendicular to the position vector given by $$\frac{y\hat{i} - x\hat{j}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $(a,b)$ and $(-b,a)$ are always orthogonal (rotation by $90^\circ$).

Comment: @Moshin, I think you just need to draw it and you will see, and never forget why.

Answer (score 2):

Because
(1) $(x, y)\cdot(y, -x) = 0$,
so this is orthogonal to
$(x, y)$
and,
(2) the $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
make the length one,
so it is a unit vector.